# How to run macro with parameter from windows command line?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

I have a need for running a Macro from the Windows command line with parameter.  For example, a macro should save, in A1 cell, the value of the parameter specified. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is using a Macro enabled Worksheet.  AFAIK, it's impossible to fire up a macro without Excel loaded.

The big question in my mind is, why would you need to run it from the commandline?